# how use PopupControlExtender with conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i have an `asp.net Button`, i want when a user click on that button:

1. if there is any Session["id"] for that user, user will be redirect to
   another page

   2.if not show a PopupControlExtender and show some link
   to user

   we cant use PopupControlExtender in code behind how i should check this condition ?

thx

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                   <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#9933FF" BorderColor="#6666FF" 
            Height="132px" Width="329px">
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" runat="server" 
                TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="Panel1" 
               >
        </asp:PopupControlExtender>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is conditionally register some javascript for opening the Popup when the button is clicked.

Lets say you define your popup like this:

```
<ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="popup" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="textbox"
    BehaviorID="mybehavior"
    PopupControlID="panel"
    Position="Bottom" />
```

Then, on the button click event:

```
if(Session["id"] == null)
{
    var script = @"Sys.Application.add_load(function() { $find('mybehavior').showPopup(); });";   
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowPopup", script, true);
}
else
{
     //Redirect;
}
```